# replace() method not working over single quote

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am trying to do:

```
df_flat = df_flat.replace("'", '"', regex=True)
```

To change single quotes to double quotes in the whole pandas df.
I have the whole dataframe with single quotes because I applied `df.json_normalize` and this changed all double quotes from source to single quotes, so I want to recover the double quotes.

I tried this different options:

```
df_flat = df_flat.apply(lambda s:s.replace("'",'"', regex=True))
df_flat=df_flat.replace({'\'': '"'}, regex=True)
```

And any of them is working. Any idea of what's happening?

I have `pandas==1.3.2`.

And the content of the columns are like:

```
{'A':'1', 'NB':'29382', 'SS': '686'}
```

Edit:

I need it because I then save that `pandas df` in a `parquet` file and copy to `AWS Redshift`. When try to do `json_extract_path` it doesn't work as it's not a valid `json` due to the single quotes. I can do replace in `Redshift` for each field, but i prefer to store in the correct format.

Comment: Why do you need "-quotes. Pandas does not treat these differently.

Comment: This is how python represents strings with single quotes

Comment: i save that pandas df as parquet file. And then copy it to redshift. Redshift returns that content is not valid json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to treat it as string:

```
df_flat = df_flat.astype(str).replace("'",'"', regex=True)
```

Comment: that's it! thank you